# Should we have a "content-types" tag?

Tags: discussion

I was editing this question: [Manage content type by admin menu link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/184129/28275) and I searched for a tag related to *Content Types*, but I can't find it. We need a tag named "content-types" or there are other tag for Content Types for related questions to Content Type?

**EDIT (after the comments in the [@Molot answer](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3388/28275)):** Or we can have a tag for the configuration *over admin/structure/types/manage/my_content_type* ?

Comment: Please note that voting on meta is different, and up/down == agree/disagree with feature requests and questions relating to how the site should move.

Comment: @MPD thanks for the info, then I must assume that if I get a lots of downvotes this is a bad idea, in this case is better remove or not remove the question?

Comment: Down-votes on meta sites don't influence what you can do on them. What matters is your reputation on the main site: You can edit posts here because your reputation on the main site allows you to edit them. Don't care of down-votes, and ask your questions. As long as you ask questions  to understand the main site, your questions are welcome.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are for content organisation. To know if tag will be useful you need to answer few questions.

### Will some people want to ignore all related topics?

Here I think not, because way too many different things may touch content types.

### Will some users specialize in answering such questions?

Again I think not - because it covers topics as varied as permissions, fields, theming...

### Will this help with search?

Not really, [fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields), [nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodes), [entities](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entities) etc already are doing way better job at this

So **no**, I don't think this tag would be particularly useful. Not really any harm with having it, but no real benefit, either.

Comment: and a question related to Content Type configuration or customization?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer You mean configuring it's fields? There is tag for that. You mean some other part of configuration? Probably there already is tag for that, too.

Comment: I mean the configuration over admin/structure/types/manage/my_content_type

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer OK, but *content-types* is much, much broader than that, and too broad tags are not helpful.

Comment: I get the point, we can have a tag for this topic, something like content type configuration in references to admin/structure/types/manage/my_content_type?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Probably. Of course, anyone with high enough rep can simply create any tag and see if people use it. But it's nice of you to post it for discussion first.  I admit that some things might use better tagging.

Comment: I will edit my question to see others points of view about this, thanks

Comment: If you want you can improve my question too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

We had [content-type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-type), but it was merged with [nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodes) because one of the following condition was true for the questions using it.

- Both the tags were used
- [content-type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-type) was used, but the question was about nodes
- [content-type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-type) was used in questions were the OP merely said *I created a new content type*, but the question was not content types

Using a tag just for a single administrative page is not necessary, also because there aren't much questions you can ask about a single page.

Comment: thanks, when you say merged with nodes, this is not the same as create a synonyms?

Comment: It has not been set as synonym. That is usually the next step, in the case the tag keeps getting (mis)used.

Comment: the problem is tag I see 0 questions with the tag and I can´t see the tag for use it

Comment: That is what you see with links to not existing tags; it is what Stack Exchange does.

Comment: I learning here! thanks ;-)